# ES6 destructuring object, default value on assignment when not used as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I've got:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const packageConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
const { jspm: { configFile: jspmConfigFile }} = packageConfig;
```

but `packageConfig`'s value for `configFile` could be undefined. In that case, I'd like to default `jspmConfigFile` to `'config.js`

Is  it possible to do this without creating an extended packageConfig object?

I realize I could do something like:

```
const { jspm: { configFile: jspmConfigFile }} = _.extend({
    jspm: { config: 'config.js'}
}, packageConfig);
```

but that's pretty messy just to get a sensible default with destructuring.

What am I missing?

Comment: How about `const jspmConfigFile = packageConfig.jspm.configFile || 'config.js';`?

Comment: Well, I thought about this, but I was trying to learn more about destructuring + leverage the fact I can safely access nested properties without checking for the existence of parent properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for default values in object destructuring is:

```
const { jspm: { configFile: jspmConfigFile = 'config.js' }} = packageConfig;
```

But this is not yet implemented in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=932080

Comment: No problem. And hi @SeanAnderson!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure ES2015 destructuring actually buys you anything here. At the end of the day since you're only destructuring a single element. You're pretty much writing a fancy way to do:

```
const jspmConfigFile = packageConfig.jspm.configFile;
```

You can assign a default value with `= 'defaultValue'` in the innermost section but I'm not convinced that's actually better than the ES5 `|| 'default'` version of it.

As a side note, you can `require` JSON files in Node:

```
const jspmConfigFile = require("./package.json").jspm.configFile || "default";
```

Is a one liner which I think is shorter. You can `import` it in a one liner directly too as:

```
import  { jspm: { configFile: jspmConfigFile = 'config.js' }} from "./package.json"
```

But I honestly don't think that's clearer.

Comment: Well, it does get me the benefit of not having to check if "jspm" is undefined without erroring.

Comment: @SeanAnderson yes, but IMO destructuring a single nested property often creates confusing code. I've considered whether or not to add this answer for a bit and decided to add it when Rob added his answer to provide an alternative to the "ES2015" way :)

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly a valid argument. I think after seeing the resulting code I'll stick with the old way, but I'm glad I at least checked out other ways.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Why do you think that you can use it without checking whether `jspm` is defined? `({ jspm: { configFile: jspmConfigFile }} = {});` throws "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" in Firefox 41.0.

Comment: Oh. I thought that was a benefit? Clearly still super new to ES6. Alrighty, I dont' see the point in using it at all for this scenario then!

Comment: @SeanAnderson a bit offtopic: as a fellow JSPM user who had to write the sort of build I think you're going to write - be very scared. It is not as simple as it looks, JSPM likes to write and alter package.json and its own config files. Double check everything and make sure things are in order. Our JSPM + SystemJS stack is getting stable just now and we used the most "standard" builder tooling.

Comment: Oh no, I wasn't doing anything like that. I had renamed "config.js" to "jspm.config.js" for clarity, but I broke part of my Gulp task because it was still looking for "config.js". So, I decided to read the value from package.json if specified, otherwise rely on the default config.js value.

Comment: @SeanAnderson it's really useful _if you import several properties_. For example `import {name, version, license, dependencies} from "./package.json"` is very nice IMO compared to the older way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you sure about `import  { jspm: { configFile: jspmConfigFile = 'config.js' }} from "./package.json"`? ;)